# Is Tensorflow always faster than Pytorch when running in graph mode

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a simple model implemented using Tensorflow and Pytorch. I noticed that the tensorflow implementation runs over 3x faster than the Pytorch implementation when I use graph mode in tf (as I know Pytorch only supports eager mode). Does that mean Tensorflow is faster than Pytorch when running in graph mode?

I run both implementations on CPU.
Tensorflow version: 2.4.1,
Pytorch version: 1.7.1,
OS: windows 7

Tensorflow implementation

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import time

number_of_neural_units = 10
number_of_points = 101
number_of_epochs = 50000
loss_eva_interval = 1000


x_train = np.linspace(0, 2, number_of_points, endpoint=True).reshape((number_of_points, 1))
y_actual = np.exp(-0.5 * x_train**2) / (1 + x_train + x_train**3) + x_train**2
x_train_ts = tf.constant(x_train, dtype=tf.float32)

loss_array = np.zeros([int(number_of_epochs / loss_eva_interval) + 1])


class Model:
    def __init__(self):    
        self.W = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1, number_of_neural_units]), name='W')
        self.b = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([number_of_neural_units]), name='b')
        self.W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([number_of_neural_units, 1]), name='W1')
        self.b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([1]), name='b1')

        self.y1 = None
        self.y = None

        self.trainable_weights = [self.W, self.b, self.W1, self.b1]


    def __call__(self, x):
        self.y1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.add(tf.matmul(x, self.W), self.b))
        self.y = tf.add(tf.matmul(self.y1, self.W1), self.b1)
        return self.y


def total_loss():
    model(x_train_ts)
    lq = (1 + 3 * (x_train_ts ** 2)) / (1 + x_train_ts + x_train_ts ** 3)

    dif = tf.matmul(tf.multiply(model.y1 * (1 - model.y1), model.W), model.W1)

    t_loss = (dif + (x_train_ts + lq) * model.y - x_train_ts**3 - 2 * x_train_ts - lq * x_train_ts**2)**2
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(t_loss) + (model.y[0] - 1)**2
    return loss


@tf.function
def updateWeights():
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = total_loss()
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_weights)
    opt.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))


def trainModel():
    t_start = time.time()

    current_lost = total_loss().numpy()
    loss_array[0] = current_lost
    print('epoch {}: loss: {}'.format(0, current_lost))

    for epoch in range(1, number_of_epochs + 1):

        updateWeights()

        if epoch % loss_eva_interval == 0:
            current_lost = total_loss().numpy()
            loss_array[int(epoch / loss_eva_interval)] = current_lost
            print('epoch {}: loss: {}'.format(epoch, current_lost))

    t_end = time.time()
    print('total time: {}'.format(t_end - t_start))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = Model()
    opt = tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01)
    trainModel()
```

Pytorch implementation:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
import numpy as np
import time


number_of_neural_units = 10
number_of_points = 101
number_of_epochs = 50000
loss_eva_interval = 1000

x_train = np.linspace(0, 2, number_of_points, endpoint=True, dtype=np.float32).reshape((number_of_points, 1))
y_actual = np.exp(-0.5 * x_train ** 2) / (1 + x_train + x_train ** 3) + x_train ** 2
x_train_ts = torch.from_numpy(x_train)

loss_array = np.zeros([int(number_of_epochs / loss_eva_interval) + 1])


class Model:
    def __init__(self):
        self.W = Variable(torch.randn(1, number_of_neural_units), requires_grad=True)
        self.b = Variable(torch.randn(number_of_neural_units), requires_grad=True)
        self.W1 = Variable(torch.randn(number_of_neural_units, 1), requires_grad=True)
        self.b1 = Variable(torch.randn(1), requires_grad=True)

        self.y1 = None
        self.y = None

        self.trainable_weights = [self.W, self.b, self.W1, self.b1]

    def __call__(self, x):
        self.y1 = torch.sigmoid(torch.add(torch.matmul(x, self.W), self.b))
        self.y = torch.add(torch.matmul(self.y1, self.W1), self.b1)
        return self.y


def total_loss():
    model(x_train_ts)
    lq = (1 + 3 * (x_train_ts ** 2)) / (1 + x_train_ts + x_train_ts ** 3)

    dif = torch.matmul(torch.multiply(model.y1 * (1 - model.y1), model.W), model.W1)  # dy/dx [100,1]

    t_loss = (dif + (x_train_ts + lq) * model.y - x_train_ts ** 3 - 2 * x_train_ts - lq * x_train_ts ** 2) ** 2
    loss = t_loss.mean() + (model.y[0] - 1) ** 2
    return loss


def updateWeights():
    opt.zero_grad()
    loss = total_loss()
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()


def trainModel():
    t_start = time.time()

    current_lost = total_loss().detach().numpy()
    loss_array[0] = current_lost
    print('epoch {}: loss: {}'.format(0, current_lost))

    for epoch in range(1, number_of_epochs + 1):

        updateWeights()

        if epoch % loss_eva_interval == 0:
            current_lost = total_loss().detach().numpy()
            loss_array[int(epoch / loss_eva_interval)] = current_lost
            print('epoch {}: loss: {}'.format(epoch, current_lost))

    t_end = time.time()
    print('total time: {}'.format(t_end - t_start))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model = Model()

    opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.trainable_weights, lr=0.01)
    trainModel()
```

Comment: TensorFlow has faster compile times than PyTorch and provides flexibility for building real world applications.For more details you can refer [here](https://subscribe.packtpub.com/is-facebook-backed-pytorch-better-than-googles-tensorflow/).Thanks!